# NativeScript + Vue.js + FontAwesome

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, font-awesome, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to use FontAwesome icon set to build an application over NativeScript and Vue.js but I can't figure out the problem since I not even have an error prompt message.

I'm following the documentation as a faithful but nothing happens. I search everywhere but.. nothing.

If you can help me with this I'd be so grateful.

Documentation: https://nativescript-vue.org/blog/using-fonticons/

Thanks!

**SOLUTION**

- Create a folder named **fonts** in the **app** folder
- Generate a style file and put the following code

```css
.fa { font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', 'font-awesome/fa-regular-400'; }
.fas { font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', 'font-awesome/fa-solid-900'; }
.fab { font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', 'font-awesome/fa-brands-400'; }
```

The font-family first part is to name the font family, and after the comma, we will write the path to those fonts.

Answer (score 16):

To get the Brands and Pro FontAwesome 5 fonts working in NativeScript-Vue, install `nativescript-fonticon`, `npm install nativescript-fonticon --save`, as described in the documentation [Using Fonticons](https://nativescript-vue.org/blog/using-fonticons/),
 and from FontAwesome download both the webfonts and desktop fonts. In the directory `app/fonts` add the `.ttf` files from the `webfonts` directory of the web download. iOS also requires the `.otf` files from the `otfs` directory of the desktop download so add these to the `app/fonts` directory as well and rename the basename of the `.otf` files to match the corresponding basename of the `.ttf` file
[image]

In `app/assets` add the corresponding css files from the `css` directory of the web font download (or the all file).
[image]

Now add the following to `app.scss` (note that light and solid don't work properly without `font-weight` properly defined)

```
.fa {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "fa-regular-400";
  font-weight: 400;
}

.fas {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "fa-solid-900";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.fab {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands", "fa-brands-400";
  font-weight: 400;
}

.fal {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "fa-light-300";
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

and the following to `main.ts`

```
import {TNSFontIcon, fonticon} from 'nativescript-fonticon';

TNSFontIcon.debug = true;
TNSFontIcon.paths = {
  // 'fa': './assets/css/all.min.css',
  // 'fal': './assets/css/all.min.css',
  // 'far': './assets/css/all.min.css',
  // 'fas': './assets/css/all.min.css',
  // 'fab': './assets/css/all.min.css',
  'fa': './assets/css/fontawesome.min.css',
  'fal': './assets/css/light.min.css',
  'far': './assets/css/regular.min.css',
  'fas': './assets/css/solid.min.css',
  'fab': './assets/css/brands.min.css'
};
TNSFontIcon.loadCss();

Vue.filter('fonticon', fonticon);
```

Now delete the `platforms` directory to make sure everything gets bundled correctly and you should be good to go. Use it like

```
  <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="top">
    <Label class="fab" :text="'fa-git' | fonticon" />
    <Label class="fal" :text="'fa-plus-square' | fonticon" />
    <Label class="fa" :text="'fa-plus-square' | fonticon" />
    <Label class="fas" :text="'fa-plus-square' | fonticon" />
  </StackLayout>
```

To make things even easier there is plugin [Vue-Fonticon](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-vue-fonticon) that is essentially the following code which I copied into `app/components/FontIcon.vue`

```
<template>
  <Label
    :class="type"
    :color="color"
    :fontSize="size"
    :text="name | fonticon"
    :width="size"
    textAlignment="center"
    @tap="$emit('tap')"
  />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'FontIcon',
    props: {
      color: {
        type: String,
        default: 'black'
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      size: {
        type: [String, Number],
        default: 15,
        validation: s => !isNaN(s)
      },
      type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'fa'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

To use it, in `main.ts` add

```
import FontIcon from './components/Utility/FontIcon.vue'

Vue.component(FontIcon.name, FontIcon)
```

and use it as

```
  <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="top">
    <FontIcon name="fa-play"/>
    <FontIcon name="fa-play" type="fal"/>
    <FontIcon name="fa-play" type="fas"/>
    <FontIcon name="fa-git" type="fab"/>
  </StackLayout>
```

Comment: First solution that worked first time round for FA5 Pro :) ty!

Comment: Here you can find an implementation and fonts within this kit: [https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/mobile/](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/mobile/)

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me using FontAwesome 4.7.0. 
Since version 5.0, the packaging of font awesome changed and using ttf is not the recommended way anymore, perhaps using font awesome 5.x is more tricky in nativescript-vue.

You can download it there : https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/

Use fontawesome-webfont.ttf as explained in the doc and rename it to FontAwesome.ttf, copy font-awesome.min.css too

in your app.scss, don't forget this (the font family is the name of your ttf file)

```
.fa {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

And remember to check your icon names on the v4.7, some are new in v5

In debug mode, when your app starts, you should see :

```
JS: 'Collections to load: fa'
JS: '----------'
JS: 'Loading collection \'fa\' from file: ./fonts/FontAwesome.css'
JS: 'fa-glass: \\uf000'
JS: 'fa-music: \\uf001'
JS: 'fa-search: \\uf002'
JS: 'fa-envelope-o: \\uf003'
...
```

Comment: Use https://nativescript-vue.org/blog/using-fonticons/ and the solution described above in @user3546128 post. Don't forget that in font awesome free icons, a lot of icons does not exist in regular, so you will have to use 'fas' class instead of 'fa'. Check on fontawesome website if your icon is regular or solid in free version. It took me some time to figure out why my icon wasn't displayed...